# Joint probability and probability of x and y

Tags: probability

If $P[x,y]$ is the joint probability of x and y, and $P[x|y]$ is the conditional probability of x given y, my first question is due to unexplained mathematical exercises.

- Is $P[x,y]$=$P[x ∩ y]$?
- If yes, then the formula for $P[x|y]=\frac{P[x,y]}{P[y]}$, how does this translate for mutually exclusive event(Is $P[x,y]=0$?), for independent events does this become $P[x,y]=\frac{P[x].P[y]}{P[y]}=P[x]$?
  All of this is not well explained in my text.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, for two Random Variables $X$ and $Y$ $$P[x,y]=P[X=x \ \cap Y=y] $$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent $$P[x,y]=P[X=x \ \cap Y=y]=P[X=x]\times P[Y=y]$$$$\Rightarrow P[X=x|Y=y]=\frac{P[X=x \ \cap Y=y]}{P[Y=y]}=\frac{P[X=x]\times P[Y=y]}{P[Y=y]}=P[X=x] $$

Note that we can similarly state (for independent $X$ and $Y$) $$P[Y=y|X=x]=\frac{P[X=x \ \cap Y=y]}{P[X=x]}=\frac{P[X=x]\times P[Y=y]}{P[X=x]}=P[Y=y]$$

Comment: I didn't understand, what's the difference between what I wrote and what you wrote in the first line?

Comment: and what about for mutually exclusive events?Was i correct?

Comment: And what would be the formula for $Pr[X=x_i]$? Is it not the element upon the length of the set?

Comment: An intersection is defined on two or more 'Events'. You wrote $P[x \ \cap y]$, but since $x$ and $y$ are usually fixed real numbers and not 'Events', it makes more sense to write it as $P[X=x \ \cap Y=y]$. 

Nope, you can't say that about Mutually Exclusive events. 

$Pr[X=x_i]$ is, loosely speaking, the number of outcomes of the experiment which yield the value $x_i$ for the Random Variable $X$ upon total number of outcomes of the experiment.